# Do I have Ubuntu on my computer?

Tags: dual-boot

Earlier I had Ubuntu and Windows in my computer. It gave an option to choose the operating system after boot. I dont remember if I removed Ubuntu when I upgraded To Windows8, but I dont get the option now to choose OS. How can I check if Ubuntu is still there in my system? And if its still there, how can I activate the option to choose OS after boot?

Comment: just try https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 1):

I booted from the Ubuntu installation CD. It autodetected the previous Ubuntu installation and gave options like: Erase all OSs and install this Ubuntu, upgrade old Ubuntu with this new one, etc. So I upgraded the old one with new. :) Job done!

Answer (score 0):

To check if you have ubuntu on your system, you can boot your system with any linux live cd-rom and check for the partitions present, using `fdsik /dev/sdx`:

```
/dev/sdx1   *           1          13      104391   83  Linux
/dev/sdx5            1046        2089     8385898+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

if Linux partitions such as swap and Linux found can be mounted on a mount point and you can check if it contains the valid root filesystem structure.

** to get back your boot loader.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the quick response :) It sounded too technical for me, so I just checked what would happen if I boot from the latest Ubuntu installation CD. I am a noob... :P

Answer (score 0):

If you not delete the Ubuntu partition from Windows then the answer is yes.You can check it by running `diskmgmt.msc` from Windows and see is there any partition with unknown filesystem.

The only thing lost from your Ubuntu is you bootloader,and you can restore it as mentioned by *OmPS*

or you can simply re-install your Ubuntu to get your bootlader back while the Windows can keep intact,but there is high possibility to lost your Ubuntu data.